# How to hide Windows console with python Tkinter?

Tags: python, windows, console, hide, tkinter

I tried renaming my .py file to .pyw. But compiling with py2exe does not make a difference.

I tried using root.withdraw() but all it does is freeze the application, prevent the initial canvas from popping up, and fail to remove the command prompt window anyways.

Does anyone have a solution?

My root is:
root = Tk()

Answer (score 5):

I ended up finding the solution on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=728170

In short, the solution is to change the line `setup(console=["yourapp.py"])` to `setup(windows=["yourapp.py"])`, otherwise, it is the same code as the rest of the py2exe tutorial.